# Error come with seo friendly url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Firstly I have coded my website in localhost than everything goes fine all URL work but when I upload it on the cloud (GCP) the URL is not working(It shows that the URL is not found)
the following code is of `.htaccess file` in localhost

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog_site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^single_post/(.*)$ single_post.php?post_title=$1 
RewriteRule ^single_post/(.*)/ single_post.php?post_title=$1

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?category=$1 
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/ category.php?category=$1 

RewriteRule ^author/(.*)$ author.php?author=$1 
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/ author.php?author=$1

RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)$ author.php?author=$1&user=$2 
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)/ author.php?author=$1&user=$2

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?search=$1 
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/ search.php?search=$1 

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also use base tag

```
<base href="/blog_site/" target="_self">
```

On cloud server the code of .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^single_post/(.*)$ single_post.php?post_title=$1 
RewriteRule ^single_post/(.*)/ single_post.php?post_title=$1

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?category=$1 
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/ category.php?category=$1 

RewriteRule ^author/(.*)$ author.php?author=$1 
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/ author.php?author=$1

RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)$ author.php?author=$1&user=$2 
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)/ author.php?author=$1&user=$2

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?search=$1 
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/ search.php?search=$1 

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and the base tag is

```
 <base href="/" target="_self">
```

The VM instance link of GCP such that you can see how website behave
[website link](http://35.222.52.198)

If I manually type the url http://your_IP/contact.php working. But if I use http://your_IP/contact is not working

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question, could you please post samples of your urls in your question along with errors which you are seeing when you hit them, that will give better understanding of your question.

Comment: sir, I add url of site at the bottom where you click on any link it says that it is not present. for example if I click http://yourIp/contact id not working. If i put manually in url http://yourIP/contact.php is working fine. It means that there is error in while creating url extension free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples only, could you please try following Rules once. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. There were multiple issues in your htaccess file, like conditions were not there, multiviews(which we came to know later in comments was ON) which made issues in your code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^single_post/(.*)/?$ single_post.php?post_title=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ author.php?author=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(category|author|search)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

***EDIT by OP:***

Please before you go forward please check .htaccess is enable it. If you don't know is enable or disable then type `----` in your .htaccess file, if it shows 500 internal error then its enable or it's disable. Then try to enable by searching on internet.

Comment: Sir I try to upload it over other server which is working accurately. Sir, I test it on profreehost.com (free host) that is working good. But on GCP, ubuntu 18 , apache 2 server is not working. Is there specific rule for that.

Comment: @PANKAJsingh, Honestly rules have worked fine for me in my local ubuntu server. That's why I asked you yesterday to check if your htaccess is enabled or not, can you confirm that once? Please try adding `----` in your .htaccess file and hit any link if you are getting 500 internal error then it means its enabled else its not.

Comment: I write - - - - after rewrite base but same 404 error came not 500 internal error. Then it means its disabled. How to enable it?

Comment: @PANKAJsingh, oh man :) I told you yesterday to check it, When I googled how to enable htaccess try this link(if this doesn't help you, you could Google more on it) https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-set-up-htaccess-on-apache/ I got from Google, let me know once you get 500 internal error then further we can look cheers.

Comment: I use this tutorial `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04` and there is no change but if I add - - - - in .htaccess then get 500 internal error. Now , where is the fault may be. I use `RewriteBase \ `currently.

Comment: @PANKAJsingh, could you please try my posted rules only and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @PANKAJsingh, ok where is your htaccess file placed?

Comment: in the root directory /var/www/html , where all the files are present

Comment: sir , now problem is resolved. I add `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` line at the top of .htaccess. That resolve the issue. But I'm not how it works,please tell if you can. I get to know from https://askubuntu.com/questions/422027/mod-rewrite-is-enabled-but-not-working/1069860#1069860?newreg=3aed800583ff4ef8a4f056658bb6a3a0 . Thanks for your kind support. You are the best. Thanks and thanks a lot again.

Comment: @PANKAJsingh, oh cool; thanks for sharing buddy, you can edit my answer now I will approve it too, cheers.

Comment: I done the above. Thanks a lot again for your kind support.

Comment: I have edit it , please check is it correct.